# Magento Admin Helper_Data not found

Tags: magento, admin, helper

I've installed an extension by BrandAmmo named ProNav. I went to clear the cache and it gave me this error in the admin,

```
Fatal error: Class **Brandammo_Pronav_Helper_Data' not found in 
/home/content/r/e/d/redr1225/html/app/Mage.php on line 516**
```

Any idea what I need to do?

Comment: Same Problem here. Did you find a solution already?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure this file exists: `/home/content/r/e/d/redr1225/html/app/code/local/BrandAmmo/Pronav/Helper/Data.php`

And that it creates this class:

```
class BrandAmmo_Pronav_Helper_Data
    extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

And make sure in this file: `/home/content/r/e/d/redr1225/html/app/code/local/BrandAmmo/Pronav/etc/config.xml`

You are declaring your helper:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <pronav>
                <class>BrandAmmo_Pronav_Helper</class>
            </pronav>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Pay attention to the capitalization in `BrandAmmo` and make sure it's correct.  Upper or lower case shouldn't matter, so long as they're all the same.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that the **Data.php** file present under your

**`codepool/extension_name/module_name/Helper/Data.php`**

2. If the Data.php present in the above mentioned directory open that file and copy the class name, Basically the class name having the Magento naming sense like

> packagename_modulename_foldername(Helper or Block) _
>   filename(Data.php)

```
<?php

class package_module_Helper_Data{

}
```

3. Move to magento root folder and make sure if the **package_module_Helper_Data.php** present in

`includes/src/`

4. If you art not see, create a php file with that name (which you got in error) under the **src** directory
5. Copy contents of Data.php and paste it in newly created file that's all. I'm sure it will help you
6. Still if you get error or magento showing nothing about the extension, just disable the compile mode under magento System->Tools->Compilation

Answer (score 0):

In /app/code/local/Brandammo/Pronav/Helper/Data.php you should have a php file with minimum the following code

```
<?php

class Brandammo_Pronav_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```